# No changes detected in android studio

Tags: github, android-studio

I'm trying to push my project in git, it pushed successfully, but some files was not pushed, and when I try to push it again, it gives me this message "No changes detected"

Answer (score 0):

Check first if those file are ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- myFileNotPushed
```

Note that a second push (without any additional commit in between) would always return "No changes detected".